# RabbitMQ Topic Exchange Message for 1, some or all topics - how to structure it?

Tags: rabbitmq, webhooks

I have a message, and need it to be handled by a variable number of queues.  The queues handle different purposes - email, audit, webhook processing, s3 storage.  Each message can have any, some or all of those topics as targets.  For example, I could have the following messages:

- message 1: audit.webhook
- message 2: webhook
- message 3: email.audit.webhook.s3

Note that although I demonstrated 4 topics, there could potentially be 100s.  Can this be handled by a topic exchange?  For example, would topic *.webhook.* miss message 2?   Could I add three topics to a queue webhook.*, *.webhook.* and *.webhook to handle all potential messages, or do I have to know the exact position of where webhook would wind up - ie: *.*.webhook.*.*.* or would *.webhook.* be sufficient to capture both message 1 and message 3?  Can this be handled at all via a topic exchange or am I looking at this all wrong?

**EDIT after additional testing**

It appears that routing is not as flexible as I was hoping.  It appears that in order to do what I want to achieve, I would have to have, for example, a binding for the webhook queue of *.*.*.webhook, and messages would always have to keep webhook in the 4th position, so a routing key for a message that was only going to webhook, would have to be, as an example "null, null, null, webhook, null, null, etc.

Is my testing correct?  I ask because this just does not seem right.  I would think there is more flexibility, ie: a better way to accomplish what I want to accomplish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the # might help as it allows you to have more than one key.  For example:

```
webhook.#
```

could be equivalent to:

```
webhook.*
```

or

```
webhook.*.*.*.*.*
```

or anything inbetween or longer.  I have never tried it before a key ie:

```
#.webhook.#
```

But that should be something you investigate.

Additionally I think that your problems could be solved by better design of your routing / binding keys.  These messages are all going to the same exchange so the should have the same pattern of routing key.

Comment: The #.webhook.# was the solution I was looking for.  Can you suggest a better design?  I could not think of anything that would accomplish it since the pattern of message distribution will be completely random (up to the client which queues they want to use per message).

Comment: The main change that I would make would be to recommend a format for the routing key.  for example webhook always goes first followed by audit if needed then anything else. so you would have webhook, webhook.audit and webhook.audit.email.s3